# FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE is undefined

Tags: php, mime-types

I uploaded a website to a server that looks pretty much the same as my local server, but it looks like that, for some reason, that host hasn't FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE defined.
Is there something I could do (without changing php.ini)?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** : PHP 5.3.2 on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE` is [only available on php 5.3+](http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.constants.php). Update to a 5.3 release to fix this problem.

Consider falling back to `FILEINFO_MIME` (and just using everything before a `;` if one is present) or the legacy [`mime_get_content_type`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) if this constant is not available.

Comment: PHP 5.3.2 installed on server, sorry, I didn't mention that. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Kor I seriously doubt that. It may be a custom php 5.3 version, or fileinfo might be disabled. Are the `fileinfo_*` functions defined? Does `phpinfo` mention fileinfo?

Comment: It seems to be a legit 5.3.2, but the only thing it mentions about fileinfo is the SplFileInfo class, which looks like the same to me, but may be unrelated to this thing

Answer (score 0):

If that isn't defined, my guess is that you'll not be able to do anything without either upgrading to PHP 5.3 or installing the PECL finfo extension. This is not something included in PHP < 5.3 by default.

Make sure that you have PHP 5.3 on your host. It might not be available by default, but some providers will let you use it by changing a configuration in an htaccess file.